# R shiny Ubuntu 12.04 installation instructions fail when installing Rcpp needed by R shiny library in R 3.0.2

Tags: r, ubuntu-12.04, shiny, rcpp, shiny-server

I am trying to install an R shiny server on my local Ubuntu 12.04 machine, and I followed the instructions here https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/wiki/Ubuntu-step-by-step-install-instructions:

When trying to do a:

```
install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
```

It goes through the dependencies, but fails to install Rcpp. See error log below:

```
* installing *source* package 'Rcpp' ...
* package 'Rcpp' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
* libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c Date.cpp -o Date.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c Module.cpp -o Module.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c Rcpp_init.c -o Rcpp_init.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c Timer.cpp -o Timer.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c api.cpp -o api.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c attributes.cpp -o attributes.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c barrier.cpp -o barrier.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/     -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c exceptions.cpp -o exceptions.o
g++ -shared -o Rcpp.so Date.o Module.o Rcpp_init.o Timer.o api.o attributes.o barrier.o exceptions.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
g++ -o libRcpp.so Date.o Module.o Rcpp_init.o Timer.o api.o attributes.o barrier.o exceptions.o -shared   -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
ar qc libRcpp.a Date.o Module.o Rcpp_init.o Timer.o api.o attributes.o barrier.o exceptions.o
cp libRcpp.so ../inst/lib
cp libRcpp.a ../inst/lib
rm libRcpp.so libRcpp.a
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/libs
* R
* inst
* preparing package for lazy loading
Error : package 'codetools' was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it
Error : unable to load R code in package 'Rcpp'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'Rcpp'
* removing '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp'
* installing *source* package 'httpuv' ...
* package 'httpuv' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
* libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I./http-parser -I./sha1 -I./base64  -I"/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
RcppExports.cpp:75:10: error: 'uint32_t' was not declared in this scope
RcppExports.cpp: In function 'SEXPREC* httpuv_run(SEXP)':
RcppExports.cpp:79:5: error: 'uint32_t' was not declared in this scope
RcppExports.cpp:79:14: error: expected ';' before 'timeoutMillis'
RcppExports.cpp:80:25: error: 'timeoutMillis' was not declared in this scope
RcppExports.cpp:80:38: error: 'run' cannot be used as a function
make: * [RcppExports.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'httpuv'
* removing '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/httpuv'
ERROR: dependency 'httpuv' is not available for package 'shiny'
* removing '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/shiny'
```

EDITED:

Manually downloading and installing Rcpp gives me:

```
sudo R CMD INSTALL Rcpp_0.10.6.tar.gz

Error : package 'codetools' was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it
```

So I manually downloaded and installed codetools and re-tried Rcpp:

```
sudo R CMD INSTALL codetools_0.2-8.tar.gz
sudo R CMD INSTALL Rcpp_0.10.6.tar.gz
```

Then followed the instructions again from the Shiny webpage from "Install R" and "Install shiny" and got a similar error but now with `caTools`, `bitops` and `xtable`, so I did the manual installation of each of them. The shiny was installed correctly.

Then followed the next steps in the instructions.

Any ideas why I got this 'was built before R 3.0.0' errors?

Comment: Before it fails to install `Rcpp` there is a line: `Error : package 'codetools' was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it`. Try running `update.packages("codetools")`, then installing Shiny

Comment: How does one re-install packages? `update.packages(codetools)` doesn't do it: `> update.packages("codetools")
> library(codetools)
Error: package ‘codetools’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it
> update.packages("codetools")`

Comment: Hopefully you noticed the redirection at the top of the page you mentioned. That page is outdated; new instructions are here: http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/server/install-opensource

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 12.04 is a pre-R 3.0.0 release.  You have to decide whether you want its long-term support and stability "as is", or if you want newer software.

You can mix and match. Read the [CRAN Ubuntu README](http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/), adjust your `apt` settings and enjoy updated `r-cran-*` packages.  With those you can then install `shiny` and its dependencies.

Comment: So I take then that the installation instructions in the Shiny website are not correct? They point to their own Rstudio servers: `install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')`

Comment: You may misunderstand. That *is* a CRAN mirror, but hosted by RStudio. The URL I posted also points there.  Not everybody runs 12.04 anymore -- I am not sure if their instructions reflect it.  Read the README I asked you to read.  Search StackOverflow for related questions. It's all been asked before.

Answer (score 0):

Manually downloading and installing Rcpp gives me:

```
sudo R CMD INSTALL Rcpp_0.10.6.tar.gz
```

Error : package 'codetools' was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it
So I manually downloaded and installed codetools and re-tried Rcpp:

```
sudo R CMD INSTALL codetools_0.2-8.tar.gz
sudo R CMD INSTALL Rcpp_0.10.6.tar.gz
```

Then followed the instructions again from the Shiny webpage from "Install R" and "Install shiny" and got a similar error but now with caTools, bitops and xtable, so I did the manual installation of each of them. The shiny was installed correctly.

Then followed the next steps in the instructions. All went well from there. Not sure why I was getting these `was built before 3.0.0` errors.

Comment: You are confusing packages install via the Ubuntu package tools (`apt-get`, `synaptic`, ...) and packages installed via R. My answer gave you a way to get these as pre-built binaries.